# Unable to pip turicreate in conda environment on Windows 8.1

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, turi-create

I am new to conda and I was trying to use turicreate package.
turicreate is not provided by conda by default.
I have gone through some similar questions about installing packages in conda.
Found that creating an environment is required and then using pip install.
So have just created an environment "coursera_env"

```
C:\Users\USER>conda activate coursera_env

(coursera_env) C:\Users\USER>conda install turicreate
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible so
lve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible so
lve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current cha
nnels:

  - turicreate

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
    .
    .
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Found turicreate using pip search

```
(coursera_env) C:\Users\USER>pip search turicreate
turicreate (6.3)  - Turi Create simplifies the development of custom machine
                    learning models.
```

When trying to install turicreate it is showing following error

```
(coursera_env) C:\Users\USER>pip install turicreate
Collecting turicreate
  Using cached turicreate-6.0.tar.gz (1.9 kB)
Using legacy setup.py install for turicreate, since package 'wheel' is not insta
lled.
Installing collected packages: turicreate
    Running setup.py install for turicreate ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe'
-u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\App
Data\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3vro8s29\\turicreate\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'
"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3vro8s29\\turicreate\\setup
.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().repla
ce('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exe
c'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dm9i0evl
\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-hea
ders 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\turicreate'
         cwd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3vro8s29\turicreate\
    Complete output (28 lines):
    running install



            ====================================================================
==============
            TURICREATE ERROR

            If you see this message, pip install did not find an available binar
y package
            for your system.

            Supported Platforms:
                * macOS 10.12+ x86_64.
                * Linux x86_64 (including WSL on Windows 10).

            Support Python Versions:
                * 2.7
                * 3.5
                * 3.6
                * 3.7


            Another possible cause of this error is an outdated pip version. Try
:
                `pip install -U pip`

            ====================================================================
==============



    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\prog
rams\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.ar
gv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3vro8s29\\turicr
eate\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-in
stall-3vro8s29\\turicreate\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', op
en)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec
(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\USER\AppDa
ta\Local\Temp\pip-record-dm9i0evl\install-record.txt' --single-version-externall
y-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\pyth
on\python37\Include\turicreate' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Pip version

```
pip 20.1.1
```

Conda version

```
conda 4.8.2
```

PC running

```
Windows 8.1
```

Is there is a way to install turicreate on my windows 8.1 PC??

Answer (score 0):

Same error for me too. I think it doesn't support 8.1.

Comment: Yes, turicreate only works in window 10. Try google colab.

Comment: Yeah, I searched on online, when I tried to import turi create on colab it shows error. I highly appreciate your help. I'm struck with my course on coursera. I need help.

Comment: This instructions might be useful. https://github.com/suryaganesh1999/dsa_journey/blob/master/tc/tc_colab.txt

Comment: I tried colab again. And it works . colab has got its own forums.its much easy .